# Debugging Dynamic Script Files In Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, debugging, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug some script on my live server in Google Chrome version 28. For this problem, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4. The script is included in the markup in a partial view as

```
<script type="text/javascript src="/javascript/jquery.inlineedit.js"></script>
```

I can find the script by clicking on the Network tab and then clicking on "jquery.inlineedit.js" in the left-hand. See screenshot below.

[image: Chrome Debugger Screenshot]

How can I debug this file?

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) might help you out

Comment: Did you forget a link?

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
debugger;
```

in your script file when you add this partial view & your script start working chrome will open up this in source & start debugging